# Display stock quantity of bundled products in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stock

Is there a way to display the stock of a woocommerce bundle in the store? *(just to make sure: -not- on the product page)*

Of course, this means that the product bundle will have to display the stock of the product which has the lowest stock.

> Eg:  Bundle consists of:
>
> product 1: 5 in stock 
> product 2: 3 in stock  
> product 3: 23 in stock

In the store, the product bundle shows: **3 in stock**

A range of snippets are available for simple product to show the stock, but I can't find anything regarding bundled products. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: well product bundle  doesn't come by default with WooCommerce so i dont think anybody can help you here.
if you purchased premium plugin  you need to ask the plugin author for this kind of modification